# How do I include the joined record in the result using squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

```
st = 'pen'
ak = '123123'
agreements = Client.where{authentication_key == ak}.first.agreements
products = Product.joins{agreements}.where{agreements.id.in(a) & (short_description.like(st) | long_description.like( st))}
```

I am trying with the above but I need the matched agreement in my result set too..

Because of this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :agreements, uniq: true
```

I cant use products.first.agreement.first.... That could be a different agreement.

Comment: This is the closest:
Product.joins{agreements}.where{agreements.id.in(a) & (short_description.like(st) | long_description.like( st))}.select{[agreements.agreement_type, id]}

But instead of id I want everything from product

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but hopefully it will be:

```
client = Client.where { authentication_key == ak }.first
products = Client.agreements.joins { products }.where { (short_description.like(st) | long_description.like(st) }
```

This returns the products associated with the agreements which are, in turn, associated to your client. If you need to get one client's agreements for a product, you could write a scope:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def self.agreements_for_client(id)
    joins { agreements }.where { client_id.eq(id) }
  end
end
```

and the call it:

```
client = Client.where { authentication_key == ak }.first
Product.first.agreements_for_client(client.id)
```

I hope this helps.